# Hide docker driver parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, secret-key, grafana-loki

Is it possible to hide docker logging driver options or at least load them from file?

I would like to commit `docker-compose.yml` to VCS but to mount `LOKI_USER_ID` and `LOKI_API_KEY` during runtime.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'

x-logging: &logging
  logging:
    driver: loki
    options:
      # \/\/\/
      loki-url: "https://${LOKI_USER_ID}:${LOKI_API_KEY}@logs-prod-us-central.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push"
      # /\/\/\

services:

  service1:
    image: image1
    restart: always
    <<: *logging

  service2:
    image: image2
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - service1
    <<: *logging
```

---

I've tried splitting them like:

**logging.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'

x-logging: &logging
  logging:
    driver: loki
    options:
      loki-url: "https://${LOKI_USER_ID}:${LOKI_API_KEY}@logs-prod-us-central.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push"
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  service1:
    image: image1
    restart: always
    <<: *logging

  service2:
    image: image2
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - service1
    <<: *logging
```

And then run

```
docker-compose -f logging.yml -f docker-compose.yml config
```

But it is unable to resolve the `*logging` alias:

```
ERROR: yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'logging'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 12, column 9
```

Which is pretty expected.

---

Another way of achieving this would to use `envsubst` and process `docker-compose.yml` file:

**loki.env.sh:**

```
export LOKI_USER_ID="XXX"
export LOKI_API_KEY="YYY"
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3'

x-logging: &logging
  logging:
    driver: loki
    options:
      loki-url: "https://${LOKI_USER_ID}:${LOKI_API_KEY}@logs-prod-us-central.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push"

# ...
```

And launch it with:

```sh
source loki.env.sh
envsubst < docker-compose.yml | docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the solution is way simpler.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) docker-compose will utilize properties from `.env` file located in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` is located in.

**.env:**

```
LOKI_USER_ID=XXX
LOKI_API_KEY=YYY
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

x-logging: &logging
  logging:
    driver: loki
    options:
      loki-url: "https://${LOKI_USER_ID}:${LOKI_API_KEY}@logs-prod-us-central.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push"

# ...
```

And simply launch with

```
docker-compose up
```